# How do I post input and select value in php include file?

Tags: php, jquery

I have an HTML/PHP file "index.php", i use jquery and php to generate and populate the second select from a value selected on the first select in index.php. The values of the generated select populates an input field using jquery. How can i post these php generated values together with other input and select values in the "index.php" at once

```
Diagram
 index.php 

    //other input 

      <select name="resident_type" id="resident_type"/>
        <option value="Resident">Resident</option>
        <option value="Non-Resident">Non-Resident</option>
   </select>

//jquery to get the selected value from select in index.php to pass func.php to query db

      $('#resident_type').change(function(){     
      $.get("func.php", {
        func: "resident_type",
        drop_var: $('#resident_type').val()
        .........
//more code
//included connetion.php
//func.php, the php generated select
if($_GET['func'] == "resident_type" && isset($_GET['func'])) { 
   drop_1($_GET['drop_var']); 
}
function drop_1(){
 --connection to the db
<select name="roomtype" id="roomtype"/>
   //some sql populating the generated select
        <option value="x">y</option>
        <option value="y">y</option>
   </select>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when your jquery scripts start to work on your page, the PHP is long gone and forgotten, and could provide no data anymore. therefore you either have to prepopulate all your elements with the data, or use AJAX (might be very slow) to load your data dynamically while your user is browsing the page and playing with the selection boxes.

if your data set is small, I'd recommend to prepopulate the data somewhere on the page, not necessary right in the controls, but somewhere in the script, so jquery could use this data to fill the proper values for your selection boxes.